# How can I get the id and the name of the pupils in the table "eleve" in a FormType?

Tags: forms, symfony, drop-down-menu, entity

You can see here my FormType.
And I would like to let appear a drop down menu with the pupils name as a value and the id as the key.

Something like this :

->add('eleve', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => array(id of the pupil => name of the pupil),

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('eleve', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'WCSCantineBundle:Eleve'
        ))
        ->add('status', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => array('0' => 'Non-Inscrit'),
            'label' => false
            ))
        ->add('date', 'text', array(
            'label' => false
        ))
        ->add('Ajouter', 'submit');
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
->add('eleve', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'WCSCantineBundle:Eleve'
            'choice_label' => 'pupilname',
        ))
```

here pupil name would be the name of the field in your Eleve entity

this would create a drop down menu with all the Eleve records loaded from the database, on submission the id of the selection would be submitted through the form

[Read more here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/forms/types/entity.html#basic-usage)

Comment: Thank you man! 
And I missed a __toString() method in my entity for it to work. I will try it.

Comment: since it worked out for you, consider clicking that accept answer tick mark, that'll help me out ;)